# What pattern is class SomeClass::OtherClass?

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

For example

```
class Spree::UsersController < Spree::BaseController
  #...
end
```

I cannot find how that class::otherclass pattern is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a "pattern"; it's just specifying which module (or class) the class in question is contained in.

```
module SomeModule
  class SomeClass
  end
end

SomeModule::SomeClass  # => SomeModule::SomeClass
```

This allows you to namespace your classes, rather than putting them all in the global namespace. You can make the nesting as deep as desired:

```
module A
  class B
    module C
      class D
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Many (perhaps even most) gems use this kind of hierarchical nesting to organize their classes and modules.